# Android full hibernation

Tags: standby

I wonder is there a way to hibernate Android tablet as if it were a usual desktop computer, that is to save its current state on the disk for the quick restoration after complete shutdown? I really miss this feature for my tablet, which boots slowly and discharges quickly even being in the sleep mode. I know that there are  power managers available, but as far as my tablet has no SIM card even, I'd prefer to switch it off completely to really minimize battery use. Thanks.